# How can I override a service implementation in IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I override the default service implementation of, say, `FrameTitleBuilder` in my intellij plugin?

I am using IntelliJ 12.1.4, I have set up the environment properly for building plugins.

Now I have tried adding this to my plugin.xml in a fresh plugin project:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <applicationService serviceInterface="com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameTitleBuilder"
         serviceImplementation="com.my.package.MyFrameTitleBuilder"
         overrides="com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameTitleBuilder"
     />
</extensions>
```

However it fails like this:

```
org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException: Key com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameTitleBuilder duplicated
```

Can anyone offer some tips please?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "overrides" attribute is a boolean (In IntelliJ 13 anyway), set it to true and the old Implementation will be removed first

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <applicationService 
         serviceInterface="com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FrameTitleBuilder"
         serviceImplementation="com.my.package.MyFrameTitleBuilder"
         overrides="true" />
 </extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find a way in the plugin.xml to make my plugin override the service implementation, I had to "replace" it manually via PicoContainer.

Take `ApplicationManager.getApplication().getPicoContainer()` and cast it to `MutablePicoContainer` and you are then able to unregister / reregister a component.

I'd still like to know the proper format for doing this via the `plugin.xml`, if possible.